# How did Steven get bail in The Cable Guy?

Tags: plot-explanation, cable-guy

In *The Cable Guy* Steven was arrested on the basis of stealing a big-screen TV, a deluxe karaoke machine and a THX-quality sound system.

Then how did he get bail?

Comment: Why wouldn't he get bail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steven was charged with Receiving Stolen Goods. This typically has a low bail, as a nonviolent property crime. Steven also had a lawyer, which almost guarantees he would get bail.